# Why is stackoverflow html not minified?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

The 'view source' on stackoverflow pages shows a lot of white space. Why are they not minified, any specific reasons.

Answer (score 3):

I think its like it was in development. The white or padding characters dont matter because it is compressed by gzip. So the difference between minified html and gzip-compressed "unminified" html is really tiny.